# stringVar variable won't change its value

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have the following function in Python:

```
import tkinter as tk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET




def Configure_Hardware():

    def add_instrument():
        ip = instrument_ip_entry.get()
        instrument_type = selected_instrument.get()
        # Implement the logic to add the instrument with the given IP and type.
        # For demonstration purposes, let's just print the information for now.
        # Update the XML file with the new entry
        xml_file = "configure\\Instruments.xml"
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()

        new_instrument = ET.Element("instrument")
        new_ip = ET.SubElement(new_instrument,"ip_address")
        new_ip.text = ip
        instr_type=ET.SubElement(new_instrument, "type")
        instr_type.text= instrument_type
        root.append(new_instrument)

        tree.write(xml_file)
    
        print(f"Adding {instrument_type} with IP: {ip}")
        if instrument_type == "Analyzer":
            analyzers_listbox.insert(tk.END, ip)
        elif instrument_type == "Signal Generator":
            signal_generators_listbox.insert(tk.END, ip)

    def remove_instrument():
        index = selected_listbox.curselection()
        ip=selected_listbox.get(index)
        if index:
            selected_listbox.delete(index)
        
        xml_file = "configure\\Instruments.xml"
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
    
        for instrument in root.findall("instrument"):
            if  instrument.find("ip_address").text == ip:
                root.remove(instrument)

        tree.write(xml_file)

        tree.write(xml_file)
    
    def on_listbox_select(event):
        global selected_listbox
        selected_listbox = event.widget
    
    def read_instruments_from_xml(xml_file):
        instruments = []
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for instrument in root.findall('instrument'):
             ip_address = instrument.find('ip_address').text
             instrument_type = instrument.find('type').text
             instruments.append((ip_address, instrument_type))

        return instruments

    def update_listboxes():
        instruments = read_instruments_from_xml('Configure\\Instruments.xml')
     
        analyzers= [instr[0] for instr in instruments if instr[1] == 'Analyzer']
        signal_generators= [instr[0] for instr in instruments if instr[1] == 'Signal Generator']
     
        for analyzer in analyzers:
            analyzers_listbox.insert(tk.END,analyzer)
         
        for signal_generator in signal_generators:
            signal_generators_listbox.insert(tk.END,signal_generator)
         
    # Create the main window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Configure Hardware")
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.grab_set()
    # Create and place the Instrument IP entry and label
    instrument_ip_label = tk.Label(root, text="Instrument IP:")
    instrument_ip_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

    instrument_ip_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    instrument_ip_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    instrument_ip_entry.insert(0, "IP Adress/Hostname")  # Set initial text


    # Create a variable to store the selected instrument type
    selected_instrument = tk.StringVar(value="")
    # Create and place the radio buttons
    
    analyzer_radio = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Analyzer", variable=selected_instrument, value="Analyzer")
    analyzer_radio.place(x=10,y=30)

    signal_generator_radio = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Signal Generator", variable=selected_instrument, value="Signal Generator")
    signal_generator_radio.place(x=90,y=30)

    # Create and place the "Add" and "Remove" buttons
    add_button = tk.Button(root, text="Add", command=add_instrument)
    add_button.place(x=40,y=60)

    remove_button = tk.Button(root, text="Remove", command=remove_instrument)
    remove_button.place(x=100,y=60)

    # Create and place the List Boxes for Analyzers and Signal Generators
    analyzers_label = tk.Label(root, text="Analyzers:")
    analyzers_label.place(x=240,y=0)

    signal_generators_label = tk.Label(root, text="Signal Generators:")
    signal_generators_label.place(x=360,y=0)

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)

    analyzers_listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
    analyzers_listbox.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    analyzers_listbox.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    analyzers_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_listbox_select)

    signal_generators_listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
    signal_generators_listbox.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    signal_generators_listbox.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    signal_generators_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_listbox_select)

    update_listboxes()
    # Start the Tkinter main loop
    root.mainloop()
```

On the GUI launch no radiobutton should be checked . Depending on the which radiobutton is checked the corresponding listbox shall be updated when the add button is pressed with the provided IP. The problem is that when the GUI is launched the Signal Generator radiobutton is checked, and regardless which radiobutton is checked the StringVar selected_instrument remains as "" which is the initial value.

I tried it to set its value to Analyzer or Signal Generator even using Intvar but the it won't change from its initial value.I also tried to declare the selected_instrument variable as global but it did not help. The most peculiar thing is that if i run it as a normal script alone (not use it as an function) the code runs as expected.

UPDATE:
As suggested by @drchicken here is a MRE of my code. First the Configure function:

```
import tkinter as tk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

global selected_instrument


def Configure_Hardware():

    def add_instrument():
        ip = instrument_ip_entry.get()
        instrument_type = selected_instrument.get()
        print(f"Adding {instrument_type} with IP: {ip}")
        if instrument_type == "Analyzer":
            analyzers_listbox.insert(tk.END, ip)
        elif instrument_type == "Signal Generator":
            signal_generators_listbox.insert(tk.END, ip)

    def remove_instrument():
        index = selected_listbox.curselection()
        ip=selected_listbox.get(index)
        if index:
            selected_listbox.delete(index)
        
        for instrument in root.findall("instrument"):
            if  instrument.find("ip_address").text == ip:
                root.remove(instrument)

    
    def on_listbox_select(event):
        global selected_listbox
        selected_listbox = event.widget
    

         
    # Create the main window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Configure Hardware")
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.grab_set()
    # Create and place the Instrument IP entry and label
    instrument_ip_label = tk.Label(root, text="Instrument IP:")
    instrument_ip_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

    instrument_ip_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    instrument_ip_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    instrument_ip_entry.insert(0, "IP Adress/Hostname")  # Set initial text


    # Create a variable to store the selected instrument type
    selected_instrument = tk.StringVar()
    selected_instrument.set("Analyzer")
    # Create and place the radio buttons
    
    analyzer_radio = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Analyzer", variable=selected_instrument, value="Analyzer")
    analyzer_radio.place(x=10,y=30)

    signal_generator_radio = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Signal Generator", variable=selected_instrument, value="Signal Generator")
    signal_generator_radio.place(x=90,y=30)

    # Create and place the "Add" and "Remove" buttons
    add_button = tk.Button(root, text="Add", command=add_instrument)
    add_button.place(x=40,y=60)

    remove_button = tk.Button(root, text="Remove", command=remove_instrument)
    remove_button.place(x=100,y=60)

    # Create and place the List Boxes for Analyzers and Signal Generators
    analyzers_label = tk.Label(root, text="Analyzers:")
    analyzers_label.place(x=240,y=0)

    signal_generators_label = tk.Label(root, text="Signal Generators:")
    signal_generators_label.place(x=360,y=0)

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)

    analyzers_listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
    analyzers_listbox.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    analyzers_listbox.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    analyzers_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_listbox_select)

    signal_generators_listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
    signal_generators_listbox.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    signal_generators_listbox.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    signal_generators_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_listbox_select)

    # Start the Tkinter main loop
    root.mainloop()
```

And then the main application :

```
from Configure import Configure_Hardware

#Configure_Hardware()

import tkinter as tk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Simple GUI")

# Create a menu bar
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

# Create a "Tools" menu
tools_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Tools", menu=tools_menu)

# Add "Configure" option to the "Tools" menu
tools_menu.add_command(label="Configure", command=Configure_Hardware)

# Start the Tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()
```

I was also able to figure out that the issue comes up when I call the Configure_Hardware function through the menu bar or even just at some point after the main application GUI is launched . If the function is called before the launch of the GUI (see the commented line after the configure_hardware import) , then it runs properly.

Comment: Is `Configure_Hardware()` called from other script which already has an instance of `Tk()`?

Comment: I can't replicate the issue on my machine. Can you give us a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @acw1668 Yes the main script of my application also has an instance of Tk()

Comment: `selected_instrument = tk.StringVar(value=""`) Should be `selected_instrument = var = IntVar()`

Comment: @drchicken I provided a MRE as you suggested :)

Comment: Use `tk.Toplevel()` instead of `tk.Tk()` inside `Configure_Hardware()`.